# android studio build tools install

Tags: android, android-studio

I tried to install android studio build tools 23.0.1 to open project online but it always fails and it says Installation did not complete successfully. See the IDE log for details. Is there a way to solve? I already installed SDK 23. I am using Windows 7 64 bit.

Comment: First step would be to "See the IDE log for details".

Comment: What IDE log says?

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing using **sdkmanager** from the **terminal**.

The sdkmanager tool is provided in the Android SDK Tools package (25.2.3 and higher) and is located in *android_sdk/tools/bin/.*

```
sdkmanager --list [options]
sdkmanager packages [options]
```

example

```
sdkmanager "platform-tools" "platforms;android-26"
```

[Docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager.html)

Comment: It does not add the build tools folder